# How to Show Long Text In React Native In Tab screen in tab Bar label

Tags: javascript, react-native, tabnavigator

as you see my text is My sales Leads. but on screen Its only Showing My Sales. so How Do I show Full Text Like - My sales Leads

```
<Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      activeColor="#FC4926"
      inactiveColor="#B2B2B2"
      shifting={true}
      labeled={true}
      sceneAnimationEnabled={false}
      barStyle={{backgroundColor: '#FDFEFE', height: 55}}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        //component={Dashboardscreen}
        component={SellerHomePageStack}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'My Sales Leads',

          tabBarColor: '#F7F7F7',
          tabBarIcon: ({color}) => <Icon name="home" color={color} size={26} />,
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
tabBarLabelStyle: {width: 400},
```

[Sample](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/tabbar-label-length)